# Ошибка выбора максимального числа

Tags: sql

Приветствую. Использую вот такой код для поиска среди строк наибольшего числового значения в паре (буква-цифра).

```
SELECT `number` FROM `orders` WHERE `number` RLIKE '^AU.*' order by `number` desc limit 1
```

Вроде бы все в порядке, запрос будет исправно выдавать нужные значения, пока не появится AU100. Запрос будет игнорировать его, выдавая максимальным AU99. Как проще всего заставить запрос верно воспринимать максимальное значение?

Comment: Префикс AU фиксирован и не меняется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы сортируете строки, а не числа. Строки сортируются посимвольно и поскольку 9 больше 1, строка '99' больше, чем строка '100'. Для того, чтобы решить вашу задачу, нужно выделить из строки число при помощи вот такой конструкции: `CAST(SUBSTRING(number, 3) AS UNSIGNED)`

Сначала мы берём из изначальной строки всё, кроме двух первых символов ('AU'), а потом переводим то, что получилось, из строки в число.

Можете посмотреть на результат здесь: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbf44a/3

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  number
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  number RLIKE '^AU.*'
ORDER BY
  CONVERT(SUBSTRING(number FROM 3), UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Здесь из строки вырезается префикс AU, а полученная строка-число преобразуется в числовое значение, которые можно сортировать уже как числа, т.е. когда сравнение идет справа на лево, а не слева на право, как в строках.

Comment: Только, `FROM 3` - отсчёт идёт не с нуля, а с единицы.

Comment: @АлексейУколов, спасибо, поправил.